# Random number wrapper class

Tags: java, performance, random

I made this class to handle any min max integer value and return a random number in the entered parameter range. I tested it to work with all combinations(I think). But is this totally wrong or written with unnecessary amounts of code? Are there obvious Java convention violations or obvious redundancy in this?

I was wondering if it was possible to do the same without instantiating `Random`, since I have read that object instantiation is more resource demanding than method invoking, like invoking `Math.random()`. I just couldn't make that work, unfortunately, as I didn't save the strange non-working code that that ended with.

I tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383286/create-a-random-even-number-between-range). However, I don't understand what the `rand()` part is, which is too bad since it seemed really simple with just one line of code.

```
abstract class RandomInteger {
     static int randomNumber;

     public static int returnRandomIntRange(int start, int end){

         if(end < start){
             throw new IllegalArgumentException("Start cannot exceed End.");
         } else if(end == 0 && start == 0){
             throw new IllegalArgumentException("Start and End can't both be 0.");
         } else if(end == start){
             throw new IllegalArgumentException("Start and End can't be the same.");

         } else if(end >= 0 && start <= 0){
             Random random=new Random();
             int range;                      
             range = end - start + 1;            
             System.out.println("aEnd > 0 && aStart < 0. 1range is: " + range);
             randomNumber=(random.nextInt(range))+(start);
             System.out.println("aEnd > 0 && aStart >= 0. invoked. 1randomNumber is: " + randomNumber);

         } else if(end > 0 && start > 0){
             Random randomGenerator=new Random();
             int range;         
             range = end - start + 1;
             System.out.println("aEnd > 0 && aStart >= 0. invoked. 2range is: " + range);
             randomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(range) + start;
             System.out.println("aEnd > 0 && aStart >= 0. invoked. 2randomNumber is: " + randomNumber);

         } else if(end < 0 && start < 0){
             Random randomGenerator=new Random();
             int range;
             range = (start - end -1) * -1;                         
             System.out.println("aEnd <= 0 && aStart < 0. invoked. 3range is: " + range);
             randomNumber = ((randomGenerator.nextInt(range)+ start));
             System.out.println("aEnd <= 0 && aStart < 0. invoked. 3randomNumber is: " + randomNumber);
         }

         return randomNumber;
     }

}
```

Comment: The `rand()` is for a different programming language, C++.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444019/how-do-i-generate-a-random-integer-between-min-and-max-in-java

Comment: Your `end == 0 && start == 0` case is included in your `end == start` case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That does look a little confusing.  The example you looked at is for C, not Java.  I would do this:

```
int random = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) ) + min;
```

It works like this:  `Math.random()` returns a `double` between 0 and 1 (although never actually equal to 1).  The full range of values you want is `(max - min + 1)` (the `+1` is because you probably want `max` to `min` *inclusive*), so this will scale the number over the correct number of integer values.  We `floor` it (round down) because we want an `int`, and finally shift it upwards by adding `min` to put the numbers in the correct range.  We also cast to an `int` since we don't want it as a double.

**EDIT:** On further inspection, this is better; no casting and rounding of `doubles`:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int random = rand.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
```

Comment: This solution works except in the case where `min = 0` and `max = int.maxValue`. In that case, you end up with overflow problems and you need slightly different logic. Other than that... +1

Comment: Thanks! that seems very simple and clever solutions, Im gonna go for that! This doesn't take into account if max being less than min, but that could perhaps just be done by using an if check and throwing and exception?

Comment: @jazzbassrob in your edit you instantiate Random, will it we more perfomance cost?

Comment: I should have written in first post that it's for shooting rectangles around the screen making them land at random x,y offset ranges. Using Random object should only be instantiated once, but maybe Random object could be created once in the main update method and be passed as parameter into the random-method every time a new random number is needed

Comment: @user1949930 I would be surprised if it made a large performance difference, but nonetheless I would try to keep the same instance if you can.  Your random method must be in a class somewhere, so I would create it once as an instance variable of the class.

Comment: It is important to reuse the Random object because when it is created it uses the current time as the seed. If you create two Random objects within a millisecond (or 10ms, depending on the clock resolution) they will produce the same "random" values.

Comment: Joni, I follow you on that :). But not using a Random object at all, instead invoking Math.floor(Math.random()). Wont this give better performance?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like the following, which will also work if start is less than end or when either number is negative:

```
abstract class RandomInteger {
    public static int returnRandomIntRange(int start, int end) {
        int range = Math.abs(end - start);
        if (range == 0) {
            return start; // Or throw your illegal argument exception
        }
        return Math.min(start, end) + new Random().nextInt(range + 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
if(end < start){
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Start cannot exceed End.");
```

I would

```
if(end < start){
  return returnRandomIntRange(end, start);
```

This would make your method more robust.

Comment: That kind of robustness might be undesirable. Frankly, I consider the IllegalArgumentException solution to be perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

> BTW Is it true that not using a Random object improves perfomance?

No (not in your case). `Math.random()` just creates an instance of `Random`:

```
//from java.lang.Math
public static double random() {
    Random rnd = randomNumberGenerator;
    if (rnd == null) rnd = initRNG();
    return rnd.nextDouble();
}

private static synchronized Random initRNG() {
    Random rnd = randomNumberGenerator;
    return (rnd == null) ? (randomNumberGenerator = new Random()) : rnd;
}
```

If you create some random numbers, just create a `ThreadLocalRandom` instance and use it. If you have speed problems, I am quite sure, it is not related to the random number generator. If you think so, profile it.

A good way to implement the required functionality is already shown by jazzbassrob.